# What exactly is the criteria for the Unicorn Hug hat?

Tags: support, winterbash

It says:

> 10 messages in chat, with at least one star.

Does this mean one star *per message*, or just one star, total?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need one star for the hat.

Comment: Okay, thank you.